# Outlook is unable to connect to the proxy server

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

Just installed Exchange SP3 (the server is running SBS 2011) and then Outlook on my laptop began giving me this message:

> There is a problem with the proxy server's security certificate.
>   Outlook is unable to connect to the proxy server *****.

I checked the certificate and it was expired, so I created a new self-signed certificate and put it in Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the Windows server. Then I took that same certificate and imported it into the same location on my Windows 8 laptop. Outlook is still giving me the error message.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Exchange Management Console to select which certificate to present to users.

- Open Exchange Management Console
- Navigation Pane: Server Configuration
- Action Pane: Import Exchange Certificate (if needed)
- Action Pane: Assign Services to Certificate

For the command line, there is a Exchange Management Shell command:

`Import-ExchangeCertificate -FileData ([Byte[]]$(Get-Content -Path c:\path\to\certificatename.p7b -Encoding byte -ReadCount 0)) | Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Services "IIS,POP,IMAP,SMTP"`

Comment: I now see where the certificates are located in Exchange. There was already a cert there, good through 2020. All services except UM are assigned to it. I exported it and then imported that into my laptop, but I'm still getting the error.